# decrypt a one of many PDFs for combining into one in Python

Tags: python, pypdf

I am working on combining many PDFs under one folder into one PDF using Python. However I know one of those PDFs has password, so I need to decrypt it, the password is: rosebud.

I think my code really decrypts this file while I am looping through all the PDF files in this folder, but I keep getting the error: PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: File has not been decrypted.

My code:

```
import PyPDF2, os

pdfFiles=[]
pdfFiles = [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.endswith('.pdf')]   
pdfFiles.sort(key=str.lower)
pdfwriter=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()


#loop through all the PDF file
for filename in pdfFiles:
    pdfReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename,'rb'))
    if pdfReader.isEncrypted:
           pdfReader.decrypt('rosebud')

#all page except first:0
    for pagenum in range(1,pdfReader.numPages):
        pageObj=pdfReader.getPage(pagenum)
        pdfwriter.addPage(pageObj)

        pdfoutput=open('allmyfile.pdf','wb')
        pdfwriter.write(pdfoutput)
        pdfoutput.close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your code does *not* really decrypt the file.

The [`decrypt`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileReader.decrypt) method doesn't raise an exception if decryption fails; it returns `0`. Since you're ignoring that return value, you have no way of knowing whether it actually succeeded.

And if the decryption failed, you will get a `PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: File has not been decrypted` when you later try to read the file.

You should change your code to do something like this:

```
if pdfReader.isEncrypted:
    decrypt = pdfReader.decrypt('rosebud')
    if decrypt == 0:
        # print a warning and skip the file? raise an exception?
```

Of course to actually fix the problem, you'll need to use the right password to decrypt the PDFs.